# Select something from mysql database and order it by count (where)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, sql-order-by

I have a problem with selecting something from my database. Here is the sql sentence:

```
SELECT name 
FROM table1 
JOIN table2
ON table1.id=table2.advid 
GROUP BY advid 
ORDER BY COUNT(table2.likes) ASC
```

This will output `name` with the least `table2.likes` to the highest value of `table2.likes`

The problem is that `table2.likes` contain both likes and dislikes. Likes are marked with 1, and dislikes are marked with 2 in the table.

Currently, if there is...

[image: The table]

...written in the table, the syntax will count both likes and dislikes so the result would be 6. I would need this result to be zero, which means when counting, dislikes have to be deduced from the number of likes. Which also means this part of the sentence: `ORDER BY COUNT(table2.likes) ASC` would have to be changed, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation with `SUM()`:

```
SELECT name 
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t2.id = t2.advid 
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY SUM(CASE WHEN t2.likes = 1 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) ASC;
```

Note:  I changed the `GROUP BY` to be by `name`.  The `GROUP BY` columns should match the columns you are selecting.

Answer (score 0):

Use a case expression to count 1 for likes and -1 for dislikes. It is considered good style and less error-prone not to join and then aggregate, but to join the already aggregated data instead.

```
select t1.name, t2.sumlikes
from table1 t1
join
(
  select advid, sum(case when likes = 1 then 1 else -1 end) as sumlikes
  from table2
  group by advid
) t2 on t2.advid = t1.id
order by sumlikes;
```

If you want to list names without like entries, too, then turn the join into a `left outer join` and select `coalesce(t2.sumlikes, 0)` instead.